# Vue.js Firebase ref by uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make my first web app with vue.js and Firebase.
I would like to understand which is the best method for querying filtered for uid.

This is my code:

```js
let tags = {}
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    let user = Firebase.auth().currentUser
    Firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/tag').on('value', snapshot => {
      tags = snapshot.val()
    })
  }
})
```

There is a more structured approach?
Does anyone have any example links?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: No one actually! 
I was wondering if I could run queries from UID outside onAuthStateChanged function.
I realize now that it is more a javascript question that Firebase.
I'm looking for the best approach to build my first CRUD in JavaScript
Sorry

Comment: You can call `Firebase.auth().currentUser` from anywhere. But it may be `null` when the user is not authenticated.